# Not sure what this jade code does

Tags: node.js, pug

```
button#someId.input-append(type="button", for="some string") myLabel
```

I know it creates a button, but I'm not sure what "for" attribute does and what input-append does. I  don't see any different by removing them. And I appreciate much if anyone of you can point me to a good site that list all possible attributes in jade.

Comment: HAve you tried online demo - http://jade-lang.com/demo/?

Comment: From your code pasted into the ^^demo I cannot really see what `for` is for, but it should be http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/label...

Comment: @u_mulder : I just used that site as a reference and totally forgot about online demo thing. I tried my code in the demo and figured out what input-append does. It just the class name. Thank you!

Comment: @dollarVar : I couldn't figure out "for" with demo either. Your link explains it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above jade code will produce the following HTML:

```
<button id="someId" class="input-append" type="button" for="some string">myLabel</button
```

The `.input-append` is merely a class for the input, and anything within the brackets is just translated to HTML-Attributes. Jade is only markup, and there's no special meaning to these. Jade will translate any `key="content"`-combo into attributes, as well as any `.class`.

Comment: Can a `<input type="button">` have the `for` attribute? I thought that's only for labels... http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_label_for.asp

Comment: @RobertRossmann I already posted that at OP's question, but look at this :o http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/output ...HTML5

Comment: Interesting. Guess I'm falling behind with this HTML5 stuff. Thanks!